# if{} vs if; and classname{} vs classname{}; What's the difference?

Tags: java, class, if-statement

What is the difference between `if{}` and `if;`?

For example

```
if(condition){
//do something 
}
```

vs.

```
if(condition);
//do something
```

And classes that has `classname{}` and `classname{};`?

For example

```
classname{
//do something
}
```

VS

```
classname {
//do something
};
```

Comment: go through the java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/) and read about the if else carefully

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between if{} and if;

Using

`if(condition){
    //TODO:
}`

Will execute **multiple** lines inside the **{}**, and using

`if(condition)
    //TODO`

will execute the **immediate line**. You can find it in this other form even it looks bad

`if(condition)//TODO`

And the answer of

> and classes that has classname{} and classname{};

[Why is the semicolon not required but allowed at the end of a class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614393/why-is-the-semicolon-not-required-but-allowed-at-the-end-of-a-class-definition)